# Getting creation date with svnkit

Tags: svn, svnkit

I am creating a document for my company with svnkit and poi it all seems going fairly well, until I stomped into the ‘creation date’ part of the document. 
I have a bunch of properties that needed to be showing, so far I was able to find it through google. I have read that I can actually retrieve the creation date  of any file by doing a SVNRepository.log and looking at the first SVNLogEntry.getDate, but most of my documents revolves around the latest data of revisions. Beeing the last comments, the person who last modified it and such, so I was trying to fill it all with SVNRepository.getLatestRevision.
 So if there is nothing else available I will have to do a bunch of fors looking for the creation date of each file and looking for which file it corresponds.
What I am asking is: Is there any svn property that points directly to the creation date of a file?

A bit of sample code to show what I am doing:

```
ArrayList<SVNFileRevision> resultReturn new ArrayList<SVNFileRevision>();
ArrayList entries = new ArrayList<SVNDirEntry>();
repository.getDir(path, repository.getLatestRevision(), true, entries);

Iterator iterator = entries.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
SVNDirEntry entry = (SVNDirEntry) iterator.next();
if (entry.getKind() != SVNNodeKind.DIR) {


    ArrayList<SVNFileRevision> aux = new ArrayList<SVNFileRevision>();
    repository.getFileRevisions(path + (path.equals("") ? "" : "/") + entry.getName(), temp, 1,
                                repository.getLatestRevision());

    for (SVNFileRevision rev : aux) {

  //So we know that rev contains date author and log        
  //System.out.println(rev.getRevision());
  //System.out.println(rev.getRevisionProperties().getSVNPropertyValue("svn:date"));
  //System.out.println(rev.getRevisionProperties().getSVNPropertyValue("svn:author"));
  //System.out.println(rev.getRevisionProperties().getSVNPropertyValue("svn:log"));

            //we add path and name
            rev.getRevisionProperties().put("path", path);
            rev.getRevisionProperties().put("name", entry.getName());

    //insert creation date
    // ? ? ?

            resultReturn.add(rev);

    }
}
}
return resultReturn;
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVNProperty.COMMITTED_DATE for each file and directory point to the creation date.

You may also look at SVNProperty.COMMITTED_REVISION and SVNProperty.LAST_AUTHOR (if you need author and revision of the latest change of the file/directory some day). All these properties are set by SVN automatically for every file and directory at every revision > 0.

```
SVNProperties properties = new SVNProperties();
svnRepostory.getFile("path/to/file", -1, properties, null);
final String committedDateString = properties.getStringValue(SVNProperty.COMMITTED_DATE);
SVNDate date = SVNDate.parseDate(committedDateString);
```

or (even better) you may use SVNRepository#info call. It returns SVNDirEntry instance that has getDate() method.